# Reaching a server from outside the network

Tags: node.js, chat, ports, demo

I recently tried to run a nodejs chat demo and test it. It worked on the same computer as the program were running on, but the chat couldn't be reached from outside. This is the code for the server:

```
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
    var wss = new WebSocketServer({host: 'put_my_ip_in_here',port: 8000});
    wss.on('connection', function(ws)
    {
        console.log('client connected...');
        ws.on('message', function(message)
        {
            console.log('received from client: ' + message);
            ws.send('received from server: ' + message);
        });
    });
```

I unblocked the port 8000 (udp and tcp as  in my router and my firewall and told someone from outside my network to open the following page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function connect()
    {
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://put_my_ip_in_here:8000");
        socket.onopen   = function()    { message('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)');   }
        socket.onmessage= function(msg) { message('received: '+msg.data);                           }
        function send()
        {
            var text = $('#text').val();
            socket.send(text);
            message('sent : '+text)
            $('#text').val("");
        }
        {
            $('#Log').append(msg+'</br>');
        }
        $('#text').keypress(function(event)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == '13')
            {
                send();
            }
        });
    }

    connect();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="Log"></div>
        Input: <input id="text" type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But my computer/the chat wasnt reachable :c
Where is the problem? The demos seems to be running fine!

Comment: how do you serve that page to clients?

Comment: Try this : var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8000 });

Comment: i will, thx for suggestion! i send the html-file to them - i did not upload it on a server or somehing